# How to join two queries based on fields they have in common?

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to solve this problem. I'll illustrate it with how fruits relate to recipes.

Background Info:

- there are explicit links between fruits and recipes (very few values 1:1)
- implicit links (same metadata between fruit and recipe) which could be 1:m

Fruit: Texture/Color

Recipe: Texture/Color.../Meal_Type

Essentially for the fruit aspect I have a query that joins several tables (ex.10), let's call this the fruit table.

For the recipe table, I have a query that joins a few table (ex.6).

I want to see for a fruit, how many recipes are possible. So Essentially, I want to join these 2 queries based on the texture/color fields to see the possible meal types. A fruit could have multiple recipes. I'm trying to use texture/color as a foreign key as if a fruit has the same metadata texture/color it should be linked.

Ex.

[example logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hSG3.png)
In this example, for the soft red fruit, 3 meals are possible: breakfast, lunch and a snack. For a hard orange fruit, 2 meals are possible: lunch and dessert.

How would I do this?

I tried to create a temporary table/view but I only have readonly access so I need another way.

Answer (score 0):

First, we can query the associated records from the Fruit and Recipe tables using a SQL `JOIN` on the custom condition or relationship as described (match fruits with recipes having the same color and texture):

```
SELECT *
FROM Fruit f
  JOIN Recipe r
  ON f.Texture = r.Texture
    AND f.Color = r.Color
```

This will return a result set containing a row for each matching pair of records, containing all columns from both tables. Each row will be a matching combination of Fruit and Recipe.

If we simply want to count how many unique meal times (how many distinct Meal_Types) for each fruit, we can select an aggregate count as follows:

```
SELECT f.ID, COUNT(DISTINCT r.Meal_Type) As Meals
FROM Fruit f
  JOIN Recipe r
  ON f.Texture = r.Texture
    AND f.Color = r.Color
GROUP BY f.ID
```

The above query will return a result set containing a row for each fruit and the number of unique `Meal_Types` counted for that particular fruit. We use `DISTINCT` to only count each `Meal_Type` once, and `GROUP BY f.ID` to distinguish the individual counts (in our case, we're counting `Meal_Type` by `Fruit.ID`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply @defines! The issue I'm running into is that the fruit (table) it's really a query is not just 1 table. It's joined with about 7 other tables to get all the results. Before I want to join it to the recipe query side of things which is joined with about 5 other tables. How would I go about that?

Comment: If you have a list of joins, typically just add to the joins. You'll add the JOIN to the Recipe table, with the requisite ON condition with the Texture and Color.